# Joomla JRequest::getVar in Detail

Tags: security, joomla

I was exploring the use of JRequest::getVar() in Joomla! and I found out that when I entered a javascript function as the value of the POST data(the value being fetched by the JRequest::getVar), it is not saving the value to my database. But when I enter a string value, it saves the value to my database.

That is awesome,  but I can't find the function that does that feature. Does anybody know and explain to me what kind of security Joomla! did on this? I am very curious how they did that.

Answer (score 0):

You should read documentation.See below URL:-
http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_and_Filtering_GET_and_POST_requests_with_JRequest::getVar
http://docs.joomla.org/API15:JRequest/getVar

Comment: Hi yogeshk, thank you for the link. I've read that, however it doesn't answer my question. What I want to know is how Joomla! skip saving my data to my database when the I entered script on my input field.

Comment: I am not understanding what are u saying but have u read that documentation that why joomla is not using golbal variable, instead of $_GET/POST it is using jrequest:getvar because of security purpose.

Comment: Basically, I just can't see the function that skips saving the value. By reading the getVar function in /libraries/joomla/environment/request.php, I can see the cleaning of values, but I can't see any function that says don't save the data if there is an html tag. Like for example, I created a form with a text input which I assigned an id of 'uname'. Then I created a joomla page that fetches the value of 'uname' and saves it to db. When I enter a string and click on submit, the name is being saved. But when I enter a value <script>alert('test');<script>, it's not being saved.